# Intermittent failure: Django Rest Framework Authentication

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a Django Rest Framework back-end, which works well but I have been experiencing an intermittent error below:

```
{
    "detail": "Invalid token."
}
```

In my settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication', 
    ],
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    )
}
```

I only secure some of my end-points, such as the below:-

```
class ViewOrder(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrderDetailSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        user= self.request.user
        queryset = Order.objects.filter(user=user)
        return queryset

    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
```

This works fine, but on one of my views where I don't secure it, I get the first error 'detail: Invalid Token'

```
class Verify(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        phone = request.data['phone']
        response = { 'status': 'failed' }

        code = random.randint(1000,9999)
        validator = Verify(email=email,code=code)
        validator.save()
 
        return JsonResponse(response,safe=False)
```

I don't know where this Invalid Token 401 response is coming from.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The response `Invalid token` convey that your given token is not correct. Please double  check your payload/header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` in settings is applied in project-level(globally), [check the reference here.](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#setting-the-authentication-scheme)

If you want to bypass the permission for your view class, you can set the `authentication_classes` in your view class to None, for example:

```
class Verify(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    permission_classes = []    # Optional
    authentication_classes = []

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        phone = request.data['phone']
        response = { 'status': 'failed' }

        code = random.randint(1000,9999)
        validator = Verify(email=email,code=code)
        validator.save()
 
        return JsonResponse(response,safe=False)
```